# Increase name attribute by 1 after adding the new section jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click event, I'm cloning the section which is working fine. I'm having while duplicating the section i want to change the name attribute like increase by 1 every time when add the new section.

This is my code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="name-field row" id="taskForm">
    <div class="form--group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="“first" name="first" placeholder="“Firstname”" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:0;"><a class="delete removeButton" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form--group hide" id="taskTemplate">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">First Name</label> <input class="firstname character" name="first" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:0;"><a class="delete removeButton" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
            <div class="field text-left">
                <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label> <input class="date" name="date" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a class="btn-success addButton" href="javascript:;" id="addChild" name="addchild">Add Child</a>
    </div>
</div>

.hide { display: none }
.field { margin-left: 20px }

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#taskForm')
      // Add button click handler
      .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
          var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
              $clone    = $template
                              .clone(true,true)
                              .removeClass('hide')
                              .removeAttr('id')
                              .insertBefore($template)
                              .attr("name", "first[" + i + "]")
          $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
      })

      // Remove button click handler
      .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
          var $row = $(this).closest('.form--group');
          $row.remove();
          $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
      });
  $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
}); 

  .attr("name", "first[" + i + "]")
```

I'm using this line of code to increase name attribute like `name="first", name="first1"` and so on when add the new section. But it's not working.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you miss something to copy from your code? `i` is not defined, so it cannot work. How should JS know what number `i` is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not defined. Make a count variable that holds the number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $('#taskForm')
    //Add button click handler
    .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
      var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
      $clone = $template
        .clone(true, true)
        .removeClass('hide')
        .removeAttr('id')
        .insertBefore($template)
        .attr("name", "first" + count++)
      $(".removeButton").toggle($(".removeButton").length > 2);
    })
});
```